# composer can not find classes and load them

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

I am using a Dropbox api package and installed it with Composer.When I try to use classes that gives me a fatal error that can not find classes.

This is my composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk": "^0.2.1"
    }
}
```

This is my php file

```
use Kunnu\Dropbox\Dropbox;
use Kunnu\Dropbox\DropboxApp;

$app = new DropboxApp("client_id", "client_", 'access_token');

//Configure Dropbox service
$dropbox = new Dropbox($app);

//Get File Metadata
$fileMetadata = $dropbox->getMetadata("/helloworld.txt");

//File Name
// $fileMetadata->getName();

printf($fileMetadata->getName());
```

My php version is 7.2.4 and the error is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Kunnu\Dropbox\DropboxApp' not found in D:\MeHDi\Projects\DropBox Api\Upload.php:6
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 {main}
>     thrown in D:\MeHDi\Projects\DropBox Api\Upload.php on line 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you remembered to import composers autoload file using `require "path/to/vendor/autoload.php";`

This is required in order to initialize and use the different composer libraries. Remember to change the filepath to where your vendor/autoload.php file is located.

Comment: i required the files manually and it didn't worked also i tried this `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` but this didn't work eighter

Comment: i had to use `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php` and then use class namespaces sorry about do not understanding your answer